# Add security group to sharepoint group programmatically on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

I have security groups created on office 365 and I also have groups on my sharepoint site. I want to add security group which is on o365 to sharepoint site group programmatically.

Could you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: You want to do this using CSOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Group createSharepointGroup(string Name, string description)
    {
        try
        {
            GroupCreationInformation groupInfo = new GroupCreationInformation();
            groupInfo.Description = description;
            groupInfo.Title = Name;


            Group group = currentWeb.SiteGroups.Add(groupInfo);

            clientContext.Load(group);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            return group;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what platform you want to do this programatically with. I'm assuming you're using PowerShell, in which case your best bet is the [`Add-SPOUser`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161371%28v=office.15%29) cmdlet, which "Adds an existing Office 365 user or an Office 365 security group to a SharePoint group."

The example below assumes you're using PowerShell:

```
$SecGroupName = "TestSecurityGroup"        # The security group DisplayName
$SPOGroupName = "TestSharePointGroup"      # The SharePoint Online group

# Get the SharePoint site
$SPOSite = Get-SPOSite "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"

# Add the security group as a member of the SharePoint Online group
Add-SPOUser -Site $SPOSite -LoginName $SecGroupName -Group $SPOGroupName
```

Some links you might find usefull:

- [Set up the SharePoint Online Management Shell Windows PowerShell environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372.aspx)
- [Use Windows PowerShell cmdlets to administer users and groups in SharePoint Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161391.aspx)
- [Manage Windows Azure AD using Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx)
- [Manage Azure AD group and role membership](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx#BKMK_ManageGroups)

(Note that users and groups in Office 365 are actually Azure Active Directory users and security groups, which is why I provide links to the Azure AD PowerShell cmdlets.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer philippe. I did it using c#.

Comment: If you solved it differently, you should post your solution and mark it as answered. (Or if this was the answer, you could mark it solved as well. :))